# Angular 2 update ngFor for one form control

Tags: angular

I have a repeating form OrderLines, wich has two dropdowns; ProductType and Product. As there are 1000+ products i want to filter the Products in the Product dropdown after selecting / changing a ProductType.

For this i use a productFilter pipe, and on form load this works fine. Although when changing the ProductType it seems the ngFor does not refresh the available values.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="product_type_id-field" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">
        Product Type
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select formControlName="product_type_id" class="form-control" id="product_type_id-field">
            <option *ngFor="let productType of productTypes" value="{{productType.id}}">{{productType.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="product_id-field" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">
        Product
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select formControlName="product_id" class="form-control" id="product_id-field">
            <option *ngFor="let product of products | productFilter: myForm.controls.orderlines.controls[i].controls.product_type_id.value" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i force to refresh the Product dropdown values without initiating the entire form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the way you obtain the value of the "product type" field to pass to the `productFilter`.

Here's a Plunkr that shows an implementation: https://plnkr.co/edit/b5FKSp06XMfQul5pYQti?p=preview

I included two techniques for refreshing the product list:

1. By recalculating the product list for every `(change)` event on the product type.
2. By using a custom pipe like you did (my preferred option).

As you can see, my code is pretty similar to yours. Here's the highlight:

```ts
<select formControlName="product2">
  <option>Pick a product...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let p of allProducts|productFilter:productForm.get('productType').value">{{p.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Only notable difference is how I access the `productType` value (but your form seems more complex). Maybe it'll work if you can fix that bit.

You can see the code for the rest of the form and the `productFilter` in the Plunkr.